# Set width and height of a lottie animation view programmatically

Tags: java, android, parameters, lottie

```
int width=30;
int height=30;
LottieAnimationView lottieanimation=findViewById(R.id.ltanms);
lottieanimation.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
```

But this isn't working for me.

Comment: make sure that LottieAnimationView is inside RelativeLayout. If not use Layout params from proper ViewGroup.

Comment: Please add the solution if you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) LottieAnimationView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = width;
params.height = height;
```

it worked for me.